# Approaches to Working With Remote Branches in Git

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging, git-checkout

Here's a random `git` question. I was looking at all of the ways to look @ remote branches. I feel like there are three ways ... maybe more.

1. `git switch --create < local branch name > origin/< remote branch name >`
2. `git checkout -b < local branch name > origin/< remote branch name >`
3. `git checkout -t origin/< remote branch name >`

Two questions:

1. Are these the three primary ways to work on a remote branch?
2. Is there any benefit to these approaches or is it just TMTOWTDI (there's more than one way to do it)?

Comment: You can work on a remote branch without creating a local branch. Technically, you would be on _detached HEAD_, but anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, none of these cause you to *work on* a remote-tracking name<sup>1</sup> like `origin/master` or `origin/feature/short`.  They just *create* a (regular, i.e., local) branch name like `master` or `feature/short` that has `origin/master` or `origin/feature/short` set as its *upstream*.

In this case, it's a massive set of TMTOWTDI, since you can also do:

```
git checkout feature/short
```

which will "DWIM" into `git checkout -t origin/feature/short`, and/or you can use `git branch` to create the branch-name at any starting commit you like, then use `git branch --set-upstream-to` to set the upstream of the name you have created.

Once you have used `git checkout` or `git switch` to be on the (local) branch (name), new commits you make will update that name in the usual way.  And as [eftshift0 commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59258465/approaches-to-working-with-remote-branches-in-git/59258744#comment104726460_59258465), you can use a detached HEAD to *view* any particular commit, including those identified by remote-tracking names.

---

<sup>1</sup>I prefer this term, *remote-tracking name*, over the official Git terms, *remote-tracking branch name* and the like.  These names do track other Gits' branch names, so "remote-tracking-branch-name" (all as one big phrase) is appropriate, but it's really easy to shorten this to "remote-tracking-branch" and then convert that to "remote-tracking branch" and then think that you could be on one of these in the same way you can be on a (real / local) branch name, and you can't.

(That, and the poor word *branch* gets beaten well past the point of its death.  We already do this to too many words, like *tree*; we can be kind and just omit the word *branch* entirely, with no loss of meaning.)